# Get data from another table then insert if exist else update

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have for example a table named

**Applications** with columns

```
+---------------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| ApplicationID | Name | Phone | DeptID | EmpNo | Email |
+---------------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|               |      |       |        |       |       |
```

**Employee** with columns

```
+-------+------+-------+--------+
| EmpNo | Name | Phone | DeptID |
+-------+------+-------+--------+
|       |      |       |        |
```

EmpNo is int and unique

When a new person applied they will be inserted to application table and if approved they got an employee number.

When a current employee wanted to apply to a new department they also need to be inserted to application table and processed

Every month I need to process the data in this table and insert/update another table named employee.

```
INSERT INTO [Employee]
(
    [EmpNo]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Phone]
  ,[DeptID]
)
SELECT [EmpNo]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Phone]
  ,[DeptID]
  FROM [applications]
```

How do I update only if the EmpNo exist in application table?

Comment: Have a look at the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement

Comment: There's a very simple operator you can use when checking if a row exists or not, and it's curiously called `EXISTS`.

Comment: You have to provide this clarification though: What if the same EmpNo exists MULTIPLE TIMES in application table?

Comment: EmpNo is unique on Employee table.
When EMpNo exist multiple times in application table we get the newest one(the lower row in table)

Comment: Empno should be the primary key in employee. Application should have an application id as the primary key and empno as a foreign key. One emp can use many applications so this is the only way that works. You should never have an employee id in application that isn't first in Employee. So your question is moot. (assuming youre using relational db)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [Employee] ([EmpNo], [Name], [Phone], [DeptID])
SELECT a.[EmpNo], a.[Name], a.[Phone], a.[DeptID]
FROM [Applications] a
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM [Applications] b
WHERE b.[EmpNo] = a.[EmpNo]
);
```

I think this query will solve your issue.